# Fedora 34 Pipewire 0.3.38-1.fc34 microphone detected but no sound input

Tags: fedora, audio, input, microphone

**What is happening**

I recently installed fedora 34 on my laptop, before I was using Ubuntu 18.04 and my mic was working fine, them I decided to change to fedora 34 and everything was ok until I try to use my microphone and I figured that it just refuses to record any input, after little search I found that fedora 34 is using pipewire, I tried several possible fixes but none worked.

**System info**

Ideapad 320 15ikb

I5-8250u

8gb ddr4

Intel uhd 620 / MX150

**Audio device info:**

```
$ pw-record --list-targets
Available targets ("*" denotes default): 
*   44: description="Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" prio=2009
```

```
$ lspci | grep Audio                                                   
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
```

```
$ arecord -l                                                           
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC236 Analog [ALC236 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**Already tested fix**

Alternatives found on the internet and that didn't work (after each possibility above I restarted the computer):

1. sudo dnf swap --allowerasing pipewire-pulseaudio pulseaudio
2. sudo dnf install --allowerasing pipewire-pulseaudio pipewire-libjack
3. systemctl --user restart pipewire
4. systemctl --user restart pipewire*
5. sudo nano /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/alsa-monitor.conf (changed => api.alsa.use-acp from true to false)
6. Tried to remove pipewire and install pulse audio, but when I try to: sudo dnf remove pipewire it said that gnome-shell will be removed

**Observations**

1. External microphones connected throw usb work just fine